# LUIS URL for container

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to use the LUIS container and am getting conflicting information. I have a test application that uses the LUIS cloud service, using the Speech SDK. The Speech SDK assists in sending the audio stream to the cloud and getting the LUIS intents. And detecting intents is actually stated functionality of the Speech SDK. See the docs at this link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/intent-recognition?pivots=programming-language-csharp

Currently, I am trying to move to the LUIS container using the same code base with the Speech SDK. However, when I try to connect to the to local LUIS container, (using SpeechConfig.FromEndpoint instead of SpeechConfig.FromSubscription) I get a connection error.

The conflicting information I am getting is whether the Speech SDK can support the LUIS container calls, or if I have to run the Speech-to-text container locally as well and broker the inputs and outputs of those containers in my code.

There is not much documentation on this scenario.  Has anyone done this? Can you point me to any docs that describe this?

Comment: Hello, can you provide the details of the connection error? Also, can you link to the conflicting information you're getting?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response.  The issue is that the Speech SDK (IntentRecognizer) does not work with the LUIS container, it only works with the LUIS cloud service.  When using containers, you have to use both the LUIS and Speech-to-text (in my case) containers and both of the SDKs.  And actually, the LUIS prediction requests from the LUIS SDK to the container do not work either. So, you have to build the HTTP requests manually and use the REST API in the LUIS container.  I have it basically working at this point. So, this issue can be closed.